# Why do I receive error when calling a function by pointer?

Tags: c, linux

I want by pressing a button called the function `my_function`:

The button is an element of the structure:

```
struct newtComponent_struct {
    ...

    newtCallback callback;
    void * callbackData;

    ...

    void * data;
};
```

Where `newtCallback callback` is

```
typedef void (*newtCallback)(newtComponent, void *);

newtComponent is:
typedef struct newtComponent_struct * newtComponent;
```

Thus I do so:

```
button->callback = my_function;
```

Where my_function is:

```
void my_function (newtComponent co, void* data)
{
    printf ("Hello world\n");
}
```

The handler of the button is doing so:

```
if(button->callback) button->callback(button, button->callbackData);
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
"Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed"
button->callback = my_function;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your `typedef` comes before the struct definition?

Comment: show us how `button` is declared?

Comment: What is `newtComponent` defined as?

Comment: @SantoshA newtComponent button;

Comment: @owacoder typedef struct newtComponent_struct * newtComponent;

Comment: It seems like the error message should really be "**Dereferencing** pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed," since it looks like you are using `button` before the complete structure is defined. I would suggest going back through your code and checking the order in which things are defined.

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, verifiable sample code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you have a sort of "cyclic reference". If you first declare `newtCallback`, the argument `newtComponent` is not defined. If you first declare the struct, the `newtCallback` goes undefined.

To avoid this kind of behavior, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct newtComponent_struct; // declaration first
typedef struct newtComponent_struct newtComponent;
typedef void (*newtCallback)(newtComponent, void *);

struct newtComponent_struct {
    newtCallback callback;
    void * callbackData;
    void * data;
};


void my_function (newtComponent co, void* data)
{
    printf ("Hello world\n");
}
```

I tested with:

```
int main(){
    newtComponent button;
    button.callback = my_function;
    if(button.callback) button.callback(button, button.callbackData);
    return 0;
}
```

seems to work fine.